# Send back to Ajax with OOP

Tags: php, ajax, oop

New to OOP, figured I'd practice a bit by sending back data from PHP via ajax. What am I doing wrong here? It works if I change the code to procedural. Here's the OOP:

```
if (isset($_POST['fruity'])) {
    $start_fruity = new Fruity_draft();
    $start_fruity->send_json();
}

class Fruity_draft {
    public $banned = $_POST['banned'];
    public $players = $_POST['players'];
    public $random_civs = $_POST['random_civs'];
    public $array_list = [];

    public $send_json['banned'] = $banned;

    function __construct($send_json) {
        $this->send_json = $send_json;
    }

    function send_json() {
        echo json_encode($this->send_json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really OOP :). You should return something from the class, not echo.
Also, you should send data from other function to the class.. in the constructor or with a method set_post_data() or something...

Simple:

```
if (isset($_POST['fruity'])) {
    $start_fruity = new Fruity_draft($_POST);
    echo $start_fruity->get_json_response();
}

class Fruity_draft {

    private $postData;

    function __construct($postData) {
        $this->postData = $postData;
    }

    function get_json_response() {
        return json_encode($this->postData['banned']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you forgot about passing a parameter to the constructor, it expects an array.

```
function __construct($send_json) {
```

In your call, you don't send anything

```
$start_fruity = new Fruity_draft();
```

This throws a warning, `Warning: Missing Argument 1`
and a notice, `Notice: Undefined variable: send_json`

Second, you should move the initialization of the class variables in the constructor.

```
class Fruity_draft {
    public $banned;
    public $players;
    public $random_civs;
    public $array_list;
    public $send_json;

    function __construct($send_json) {
        $this->banned = 'banned';
        $this->players = 'players';
        $this->random_civs = 'random_civs';


        $this->send_json = $send_json;
        $this->send_json['banned'] = $this->banned;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be right (if I add the curly bracket that you omitted by mistake), but I'm receiving a JSON parse error. Is this perhaps because json_encode is not included in the code? Not sure where to add it.

Comment: it's not by mistake, put the rest of the class, the `send_json` function

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll need to invest more time in OOP.